# Erro ao efetuar Update usando EntityFramework Core

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, ddd

Tenho um projeto em camadas usando DDD e estou tendo problemas ao fazer UPDATE de um registro da minha classe PessoaSituacao com o EF Core.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```js
public Task Handle(UpdatePessoaSituacaoCommand message, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            if (!message.IsValid())
            {
                NotifyValidationErrors(message);
                return Task.CompletedTask;
            }

            var pessoaSituacao = new PessoaSituacao(message.Id, message.Descricao);
            var existingPessoaSituacao = _pessoaSituacaoRepository.GetById(pessoaSituacao.Id);

            if (existingPessoaSituacao != null && existingPessoaSituacao.Id != pessoaSituacao.Id)
            {
                if (!existingPessoaSituacao.Equals(pessoaSituacao))
                {
                    Bus.RaiseEvent(new DomainNotification(message.MessageType, "Já existe uma Situação cadastrada com o ID informado."));
                    return Task.CompletedTask;
                }
            }

            _pessoaSituacaoRepository.Update(pessoaSituacao);

            if (Commit())
            {
                Bus.RaiseEvent(new PessoaSituacaoUpdatedEvent(pessoaSituacao.Id, pessoaSituacao.Descricao));
            }

            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }
```

Se eu comentar o trecho abaixo, o problema não acontece, só que não posso deixá-lo comentado...

```js
var existingPessoaSituacao = _pessoaSituacaoRepository.GetById(pessoaSituacao.Id);

            if (existingPessoaSituacao != null && existingPessoaSituacao.Id != pessoaSituacao.Id)
            {
                if (!existingPessoaSituacao.Equals(pessoaSituacao))
                {
                    Bus.RaiseEvent(new DomainNotification(message.MessageType, "Já existe uma Situação cadastrada com o ID informado."));
                    return Task.CompletedTask;
                }
            }
```

Mas pq isso acontece e como eu posso resolvê-lo?

Comment: Amigo, quando você busca algum registro do banco de dados com o Entity, isso fica salvo em um cache do framework, (é salvo uma referência do objeto), porém, quando vamos atualizar um objeto, o ID é o certo, mas no cache do EF a referência é outra, e isso causa um conflito, pois ele tenta adicionar um objeto com o mesmo ID no cache.

O ideal é que no update, você primeiro busque por ID o objeto que quer alterar, e nesse objeto carregado, você atribui as mudanças, e aí sim, manda o update

Comment: O Ruim, é que de acordo com a minha arquitetura, não creio que seria uma boa prática fazer isso... Esse projeto eu fiz idêntico ao do Eduardo Pires, o Equinox... O Dele funciona corretamente, mas o meu não.... Não sei pq.....

Comment: Sim, conheço o projeto do Eduardo, mas o Entity não ajuda, no mundo real, nem tudo é tão bonito, isso acontece também porque no Equinox muitas coisas são carregadas com o AsNoTracking, e isso impede que as entidades sejam salvas no cache, evitando o problema que você passa.

Comment: Ahhhhh então o problema era o AsNoTracking!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! Acrescentei ele na minha função GetById e parou de dar erro kkkkkkk Valeu @ Gustavo Santos!!!!!

Comment: É nóis mano! Hahaha

Comment: Comenta o Post principal para eu definir como resposta?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Amigo, quando você busca algum registro do banco de dados com o Entity, isso fica salvo em um cache do framework, (é salvo uma referência do objeto), porém, quando vamos atualizar um objeto, o ID é o certo, mas no cache do EF a referência é outra, e isso causa um conflito, pois ele tenta adicionar um objeto com o mesmo ID no cache.

Nesse caso, você possui duas alternativas:

- Primeiro: busque por ID o objeto que quer alterar, e nesse objeto carregado, você atribui as mudanças, e aí sim, manda o update.
- Segundo: quando for carregar as entidades, utilize o AsNoTracking, isso vai fazer com que as entidades não sejam salvas no cache do Entity Framework, evitando esse problema nos updates e deletes.

Comment: Obrigado pela excelente ajuda @Gustavo Santos!!! :)